# Индекс и сортировка в elasticsearch

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, elasticsearch

есть задача сортировать по текстовому полю в алфавитном(и обратно) порядке.
текстовое поле может содержать вначале пробел или кавычки, что ломает сортировку.
Каким образом можно игнорировать специальные символы, либо при создании индекса либо при сортировке ?

в инете находил что надо писать свои анализаторы, но как это сделать в c# толкового не нашел ничего. В эластике я полный ноль, а время поджимает(

создание индекса:

```
await _elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync(_options.Value.Index[nameof(TestDto)], c => c
        .Map<TestDto>(m => m.AutoMap().Properties(p => p.Text(t => t.Name(n => n.ShortName)
        .Fields(f => f.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword").IgnoreAbove(256))
        .Keyword(k => k
        .Name("keyword_lowercase")
        .Normalizer("lowercase")
        .IgnoreAbove(256))))))
    );
```

Буду очень признателен помощи, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем вроде как сам разобрался, возможно кому-то будет полезно.

```
await _elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync(_options.Value.Index[nameof(TestDto)], c => c
            .Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(a => a
                .CharFilters(cf => cf.PatternReplace("char_ignore", pr => pr.Pattern(@"\s|""").Replacement("")))
            .Normalizers(n => n
            .Custom("special_char_ignore", cn => cn
            .Filters("lowercase")
            .CharFilters("char_ignore")))))
            .Map<TestDto>(m => m.AutoMap().Properties(p => p.Text(t => t.Name(n => n.ShortName)
                .Fields(f => f.Keyword(k => k.Name("keyword").IgnoreAbove(256))
                .Keyword(k => k
                .Name("keyword_lowercase")
                .Normalizer("special_char_ignore")
                .IgnoreAbove(256))))))
            );
```